# How to load jQm modal on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, jqmodal

Hi I am using jQm Window to load modal window.

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#how

i am trying to

```
jqmShow
    Show jqModal element(s).

    $('#dialog').jqmShow();
    $('.dialogs').jqmShow();
```

but it throws some JS error,

but it does not load on the page load, please guide me for the same.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer , it was quite easy using jqmShow();

```
$('#alert-box').jqm({ajax: 'alert-note.html' , modal:true});
$('#alert-box').jqmShow();
```

:)

thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Seriouly why do you have to make life complicated for yourself? Just put a div on your page that is hidden that floats in the center like this

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:50%; left:50%;" hidden="true" id="Messagee">
//Your Message or Html Here
</div>
```

and then when you need to show it have a function that does

```
$("#Message").html("<p>My Message</p>"); 
$("#Message").show();
```

You don't need a crazy javascript module that does modals, you can really make your life easy. Oh and if you want some nice effects use the $("#Message").fadeIn(500); instead!

Comment: It is some special case, so I have to use that JS. btw thanks for the suggestion. Thanks it would help.